# why does .net core "Return" verb inside a controller adds "plaintext.css" ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I was doing some testing with MVC6 .net core, and did a quick hack to return a bootstrap html code by putting dirtyHTML directly inside a controller.
The HTML contains the official example of bootstrap inside a literal string.
Just a quick way of returning some bootstrap html, (as i experiment with controller functionality), to my surprise when i go to a page using a web browser, all html text is shown like plain text, its not rendered.

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers 
{
 public class MariaController
 {
    [HttpGet("/index")]
    public string index()
    {
        string dirtyHtml;

      dirtyHtml = 
            @"<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang=""en"">
            <head>
              <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
              <meta charset=""utf-8"">
              <meta name=""viewport"" content=""width=device-width, initial-scale=1"">
              <link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"">
              <script src=""https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js""></script>
              <script src=""https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js""></script>
            </head>
            <body>

            <div class=""container"">
              <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
            ";

        return dirtyHtml;
    }
   }
```

When going to debug mode, initially they show the same asci text, but using firefox i see there is a line inserted before my page code:

```
<HTML><head>
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="resource://gre-resources/plaintext.css" 
  title="Wrap Long Lines">`
```

So then i thought, let's look around in the solution and search  for "Wrap Long Lines".. as to see where it comes from,... this is however not found.

So where does that come from ? (as the solution doesnt contain plaintext.css either).  And more important to me, can it be disabled?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative of @dotnetstep's way is using `Produces` attribute:

```
[HttpGet("/index")]
[Produces("text/html")]
public string Index()
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you want to achive but following thing is way to go.

1. "Wrap Long Lines" and css related to that are internal to firefox browser.
2. You are saying that you return html and it display like html but it does not render html and for that do following thing.

   ```
   [HttpGet("/index")]
   public IActionResult index()
   {
       string dirtyHtml;

     dirtyHtml = 
           @"<!DOCTYPE html>
           <html lang=""en"">
           <head>
             <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
             <meta charset=""utf-8"">
             <meta name=""viewport"" content=""width=device-width, initial-scale=1"">
             <link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"">
             <script src=""https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js""></script>
             <script src=""https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js""></script>
           </head>
           <body>

           <div class=""container"">
             <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
           ";

       return Content(dirtyHtml,"text/html");
   }
   ```

See I have return IActionResult and Use Content from return.

Reason for this is when you return string it will display as string and if it is html then it will become encoded as you did not tell browser content type so it consider "text/plain".

Comment: but it includes <!DOCTYPE HTML> which means html 5 doc

Comment: But Before it reach to browser it contenttype set as you did not specify any content type so it consider "text/plain". You can open html5 doc in notepad and at that time it will not reder ui same case when it did not found proper content type.

Comment: ïts the before, i didnt get, as where that happens, but its answered by @adem caglin

Comment: I have no problem but answer given @adem Catlin is alternate way of doing thing

Comment: oh i missed it and then tested the other answer, i was suspecting you'd edited the dirty string with something; i didn't saw a change there so in the beginning; then i red your text below it, i missed your altered return 'content' both are working. thanks